# do not allow the user to enter zero's with decimal in the flex text input box

Tags: apache-flex, string, input, decimal

i have a text input box in flex. i wanted to call a function if the text of text input box is >0. i have parsed the text into integer ,parseInt(str.text) where str.text is 0.03(something like this) then it becomes zero, as i am parsing into integer.

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just do Number(str.text), that will give you a float. Use isNaN() to check if it's actually a number that was parsed.

Answer (score 0):

```
var n:Number = Number(textInput.text);
if (!isNaN(n)) {
  // do whatever
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have done it like below
parseFloat(str.text)>0
{
  // statements;
}
so thts if user enters 0.00 or 00.00 or 00000.0 or 000.000 it will not allow , if he enters 0.01 or 0.89 or anything greater than zero will be allowed.
Anyway thanks for the response.